# Datatables - Using fnCreatedRow to add details rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have used this code in order to add extra rows under each original row with the fnCreatedRow callback of Datatables. The original row is correctly updated but the additional rows are removed after the callback...

```js
fnCreatedRow: function(nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
  var $nRow = $(nRow),
    $content = $(),
    numIndex = 3;

  $nRow.find('td').eq(3).html('');
  // We add one or multiple sub rows under each row in order to show the accounts details of the client

  $.each(aData[3][0], function(e, i) {

    if (e === 'profileId') {
      return true;
    }

    $content = $content.add($nRow.clone().find('td').eq(numIndex).html(i).end().end());
    ++numIndex;
  });

  $nRow.after($('<tr>').append($content).html());
}
```

Is there a more appropriate callback ?
I think it works if I do those things after the entire table was created but if the plugin does a loop...why not use it ?

I'm not the only one who had this problem : 
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21354/using-fncreatedrow-to-add-detail-rows-working-but-not

I want to add that the json that i retrieve contain an array for the fourth column. It's this array that i use in order to construct those subrows. I think it doesn't work 'cause Datatables expect one array or something different than a string.

Comment: The rows disappears because dataTables not is aware of them. You simply cannot do it this way.

Comment: Is there a way to ensure that Datatables is aware of them ? To update the internal data with new informations or something ?

Comment: Yes, use the API - `table.row.add()` / `table.fnAddRow()`, but you should also consider @Dontfeedthecode approach with child rows.

Comment: The solution of @Dontfeedthecode is interesting but yours fit more to my needs. Problem is ...I have this error `invalid 'in' operand a` when using table.row.add(). (I'd tried to upgrade my version to Datatables 1.10.10 but it still doesn't work)

Comment: Can you create a fiddle showing what you are trying to do? You can use this as starting point -> http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/729/ is has dataTables 1.10.9

Comment: Apparently, it's the table.row.add() that throws me that error and if i remove the content of the **fourth** td of the row that i add ...it works. Strange, isn't it ?

Comment: In the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/740/ it works.Even if it is simpler than my code, i don't understand why it's different !

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking into appending your child rows with row.child() as they do in this example:

https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

The example does differ, however, as they are rendering the detail rows via a click event - however the way in which they are rendered maybe the key to solving your issue rather than using $content.add.

Comment: In this example, the `format` function returns the html content of a cell not of a row. I don't see how you would do your code. I don't want to use a button nor a table inside a table. I want one simple classic table...

Comment: @mysthiq all format does is return a string, I'm talking about using row.child( $your_child_row ) to append content to the row instead of $content.add